# Django notify user about an event and require a response

Tags: django, websocket, notifications, django-channels

I am developing a food ordering web app with Django. 
When a user submits an order, i want the restaurant to be notified about this order and either accept it or reject it. In both cases, i need to notify the user if his order was accepted or not. I've come across django notifications and django channels but i don't know which one i should choose. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would say django-channels is more suitable when you need to have a high iteration between your backend and frontend (like a chat or some real-time like geolocation position for deliveries)

django-notifications seems more suitable for your propose, when you need to open communication (often) async with your frontend to notify some backend change like some finished task, or some background change